# WPF Panel in container without PositiveInfinity

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to create a custom TabControl, where when the items combined width exceeds the width of the panel the items are in, they will resize unified, like the Chrome tabs. I also want to panel to be scrollable when the items can't be contained with their MinWidth. All that works fine already.

My problem is, i want, like the Chrome tabcontrol, to have a "New Tab" button besides the tab panel. To accomplish this, i need to wrap the tab panel and the button in the scrollviewer somehow. But when using a StackPanel or Grid, my tab panel now has it's width with PositiveInfinity, and the MeassureOverride now can't compute the width, of cause.

**Here is my code:**

```
<ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True"
                          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
                          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">

                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <local:TabPanel Grid.Column="0"
                              IsItemsHost="True" 
                              SnapsToDevicePixels="True" 
                              Margin="6,5,6,0"/>

                    <Button Grid.Column="1"
                            Margin="0,5,0,0"
                            KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2"
                            Style="{StaticResource NewTabButtonStyle}" 
                            Visibility="{Binding Path=AllowAddNew, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
                            ToolTip="Add a New tab">

                        <Viewbox RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"
                                 SnapsToDevicePixels="True" >
                            <Grid>
                                <Line X1="0" Y1="20" X2="40" Y2="20" Stroke="{Binding Path=TabForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:ExtendedTabControl}}}" StrokeThickness="7"/>
                                <Line X1="20" Y1="0" X2="20" Y2="40" Stroke="{Binding Path=TabForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:ExtendedTabControl}}}" StrokeThickness="7"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Viewbox>
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
            </ScrollViewer>
```

If i remove the grid and the button inside the ScrollViewer, the TabPanel now has a width and it works.

So how can i accomplish to have my button right of the TabPanel without the TabPanel having Width=PositiveInfinity?

Comment: i think you would have to implement that logic in a converter there is no way i can imaginge wpf can do that. You could position the plus button on the right of the last menuitem by multiplying the width of a tab with the number of tabs

Comment: @LasseO: What's the expected width of the `Button`? Try to set the `Width` of first `ColumnDefinition` to `*` and the `Width` of the other one to a fixed width, or set the `Width` property of the `Button` to a fixed width.

Comment: ever resolved this issue in a propper fashion?

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this do the trick for you? Of cause it needs some touching up but it does the trick. Need to refine the bindings but maybe its can point into a direction

```
        <Grid Height="30"  Background="LightBlue" Width="400">

            <UniformGrid Rows="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,40,0" Name="uni">

                <Border CornerRadius="12,12,0,0" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="2" MaxWidth="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="tabitem">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Viewbox>
                            <Path Fill="Black" Data="M 22.205078 2 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 0 0 21.21875 2.8378906 L 20.246094 8.7929688 C 19.076509 9.1331971 17.961243 9.5922728 16.910156 10.164062 L 11.996094 6.6542969 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 0 0 10.708984 6.7597656 L 6.8183594 10.646484 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 0 0 6.7070312 11.927734 L 10.164062 16.873047 C 9.583454 17.930271 9.1142098 19.051824 8.765625 20.232422 L 2.8359375 21.21875 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 0 0 2.0019531 22.205078 L 2.0019531 27.705078 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 0 0 2.8261719 28.691406 L 8.7597656 29.742188 C 9.1064607 30.920739 9.5727226 32.043065 10.154297 33.101562 L 6.6542969 37.998047 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 0 0 6.7597656 39.285156 L 10.648438 43.175781 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 0 0 11.927734 43.289062 L 16.882812 39.820312 C 17.936999 40.39548 19.054994 40.857928 20.228516 41.201172 L 21.21875 47.164062 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 0 0 22.205078 48 L 27.705078 48 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 0 0 28.691406 47.173828 L 29.751953 41.1875 C 30.920633 40.838997 32.033372 40.369697 33.082031 39.791016 L 38.070312 43.291016 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 0 0 39.351562 43.179688 L 43.240234 39.287109 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 0 0 43.34375 37.996094 L 39.787109 33.058594 C 40.355783 32.014958 40.813915 30.908875 41.154297 29.748047 L 47.171875 28.693359 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 0 0 47.998047 27.707031 L 47.998047 22.207031 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 0 0 47.160156 21.220703 L 41.152344 20.238281 C 40.80968 19.078827 40.350281 17.974723 39.78125 16.931641 L 43.289062 11.933594 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 0 0 43.177734 10.652344 L 39.287109 6.7636719 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 0 0 37.996094 6.6601562 L 33.072266 10.201172 C 32.023186 9.6248101 30.909713 9.1579916 29.738281 8.8125 L 28.691406 2.828125 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 0 0 27.705078 2 L 22.205078 2 z M 23.056641 4 L 26.865234 4 L 27.861328 9.6855469 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 0 0 28.603516 10.484375 C 30.066026 10.848832 31.439607 11.426549 32.693359 12.185547 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 0 0 33.794922 12.142578 L 38.474609 8.7792969 L 41.167969 11.472656 L 37.835938 16.220703 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 0 0 37.796875 17.310547 C 38.548366 18.561471 39.118333 19.926379 39.482422 21.380859 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 0 0 40.291016 22.125 L 45.998047 23.058594 L 45.998047 26.867188 L 40.279297 27.871094 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 0 0 39.482422 28.617188 C 39.122545 30.069817 38.552234 31.434687 37.800781 32.685547 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 0 0 37.845703 33.785156 L 41.224609 38.474609 L 38.53125 41.169922 L 33.791016 37.84375 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 0 0 32.697266 37.808594 C 31.44975 38.567585 30.074755 39.148028 28.617188 39.517578 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 0 0 27.876953 40.3125 L 26.867188 46 L 23.052734 46 L 22.111328 40.337891 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 0 0 21.365234 39.53125 C 19.90185 39.170557 18.522094 38.59371 17.259766 37.835938 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 0 0 16.171875 37.875 L 11.46875 41.169922 L 8.7734375 38.470703 L 12.097656 33.824219 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 0 0 12.138672 32.724609 C 11.372652 31.458855 10.793319 30.079213 10.427734 28.609375 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 0 0 9.6328125 27.867188 L 4.0019531 26.867188 L 4.0019531 23.052734 L 9.6289062 22.117188 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 0 0 10.435547 21.373047 C 10.804273 19.898143 11.383325 18.518729 12.146484 17.255859 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 0 0 12.111328 16.164062 L 8.8261719 11.46875 L 11.523438 8.7734375 L 16.185547 12.105469 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 0 0 17.28125 12.148438 C 18.536908 11.394293 19.919867 10.822081 21.384766 10.462891 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 0 0 22.132812 9.6523438 L 23.056641 4 z M 25 17 C 20.593567 17 17 20.593567 17 25 C 17 29.406433 20.593567 33 25 33 C 29.406433 33 33 29.406433 33 25 C 33 20.593567 29.406433 17 25 17 z M 25 19 C 28.325553 19 31 21.674447 31 25 C 31 28.325553 28.325553 31 25 31 C 21.674447 31 19 28.325553 19 25 C 19 21.674447 21.674447 19 25 19 z" />
                        </Viewbox>
                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center">Name of tab</TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </UniformGrid>
            <Border Grid.Column="1" Width="30" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="15" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <Border.Margin>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource mutliply}">
                        <Binding ElementName="uni" Path="Children.Count" />
                        <Binding ElementName="tabitem" Path="ActualWidth" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Border.Margin>
                <Button BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="Transparent" Padding="0">
                    +
                </Button>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
```

[image]

requires a converter:

```
public class Multiplier : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Thickness thic = new Thickness(1,0,0,0);
        foreach (var value in values)
        {
            thic.Left = thic.Left * System.Convert.ToDouble(value);
        }
        thic.Left = thic.Left + 5;
        return thic;
    }//END Convert 

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }//END ConvertBack 

}//END class MultiVisibilityConverter : IMultiValueConverter
```